# Why is there a metallic clip on the connector of a washing machine knob?

Tags: appliances

My friend asked me to 3d print him a washing machine knob, because the original broke. In the meantime, he already replaced it with another, and it's hard to get off, so I don't have a picture of what's going on there. Here is a picture of its backside:
[image: Knob_backside]

What I don't understand is the significance of the metallic clip that "hugs" the connector. I am aware of axles with a "D" cross section. But, why go to the lengths of adding a separate element to the design, and not just include the straight line part in the monoblock design of the knob? Am I able to just make a modified connector which as a whole includes a D-female connector, or is there some strange reason that I have to be faithful to the design of a picture and have to go to the additional trouble of finding such a clip?

Help with adding question tags is highly appreciated!

Comment: That clip adds a lot of strength. D-shaped shafts impart concentrated stress at one end of the flat surface when turning. That design has that concentrated force applied to the steel clip, rather than plastic.

Comment: Is there a reason why you've used an image with a watermark right on top of the part we're supposed to look at? Or indeed why there's a watermark at all?

Comment: I myself find watermarking... strange in such a kind of picture, it's not like washing machine knobs are very used around. Alas, I haven't any alternative pic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clip or, more correctly, spring clip stops the knob sliding off easily by either the operator pulling or the vibrations of the machine.

It is not the only method that has been used in the past, grub screws (but they can vibrate loose), however it seems to be the most popular unless the manufacturer has gone to keypads and digital.

Some plastic knobs have "ears" that engage in ridges on the shaft - but then those switches need to be specially made, while the spring clip solution means the switch is cheaper...

Comment: So the spring clip has the "tight fit" role? I took for granted that the already existing plastic hole would lead to a press fit.

Comment: A plastic knob with correctly shaped hole still tends to grate the plastic away; unless everyone is so very careful. I’d try getting a metal knob off a stove.